# Web Bluetooth Bypass Pairing Screen

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, web-bluetooth

The [BLE Peripheral Simulator app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.github.webbluetoothcg.bletestperipheral), combined with the [Web Bluetooth Samples](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/index.html), is a tremendous resource for developers.

Once a device is paired, is there any way through Web Bluetooth to bypass the pairing screen and go straight to the app?

[image: Pairing Screen]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible. [Code Source](https://medium.com/@loginov_rocks/how-to-make-a-web-app-for-your-own-bluetooth-low-energy-device-arduino-2af8d16fdbe8). Not my code though.

```js
// Selected device object cache
let deviceCache = null;

// Launch Bluetooth device chooser and connect to the selected
function connect() {
    return (deviceCache ? Promise.resolve(deviceCache) :
        requestBluetoothDevice())
        .then(device => connectDeviceAndCacheCharacteristic(device))
        .then(characteristic => startNotifications(characteristic))
        .catch(error => log(error));

function requestBluetoothDevice() {
    log('Requesting bluetooth device...');

    return navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({
      filters: [{services: [myService]}],
    })
        .then(device => {
          log('"' + device.name + '" bluetooth device selected');
          deviceCache = device;

        // Listen for disconnet event
        deviceCache.addEventListener('gattserverdisconnected',
        handleDisconnection);

          return deviceCache;
        });
}
```

[Also, there is a way of reconnecting after site refresh](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/issues/428), but it is [not implemented yet](https://github.com/WebBluetoothCG/web-bluetooth/blob/master/implementation-status.md)

Comment: I wonder how you are caching the device as it has huge data for bluetooth device. I tried with localStorage and it is not allowing me to keep the whole object. Can you share some infromation.

Comment: I looking to reconnect on browser refresh.

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented a new permissions backend as well as two APIs that will enable previously permitted Bluetooth devices to be used.

The new permissions backend is implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth-new-permissions-backend. The new backend will persist device permissions granted through [`requestDevice()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-requestdevice) until the permission is reset in Site Settings or the Page Info dialog box.

The [`getDevices()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetooth-getdevices) and [`watchAdvertisements()`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#dom-bluetoothdevice-watchadvertisements) are implemented behind the chrome://flags/#enable-experimental-web-platform-features flag for Chrome 85.0.4165.0 or greater. The recommended use of these APIs is to use `getDevices()` to retrieve an array of permitted BluetoothDevices and then calling `watchAdvertisements()` on these devices to start a scan. When advertisement packets are detected from the devices, the [`advertisementreceived`](https://webbluetoothcg.github.io/web-bluetooth/#eventdef-bluetoothdevice-advertisementreceived) Event will be fired on the device that it corresponds to. At this point, the Bluetooth device is in range and can be connected to.

Please give this new feature a try, and file any bugs at https://crbug.com using the Blink>Bluetooth component.